# SUMIF for first 5 cells meeting criteria

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, sumifs

Simple Excel Table such as

```
       A     B
    1  John  5
    2  John  7
    3  John  9
    4  Jill  25
    5  John  21
    6  John  22
    7  Jill  50
    8  John  100
    9  John  2000
   10  Jack  4
```

Using SUMIF, we can return the total assigned to John.

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"John",B:B)
```

Is there a way to return only the first 5 values that match the criteria?  Or is there a way to return the 5 smallest values for John?  Either would work.

Comment: Are all values in column B unique?  Would it be acceptible if it summed more than 5 numbers if the fifth-smallest had duplicates?

Comment: @jbarker2160 all values in B are unique.

Comment: Can we use all of Column C?

Comment: Are the entries in column B strictly increasing? What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Can I cheat with some VBA?

Comment: @XORLX the entries in B are strictly increasing for the unique groups in A.  For example, John's values are in increasing order and Jill's values are in increasing order but Jill may have a lower value between John's higher values.

Comment: @jbarker2160 unfortunately macros are not enabled on this workstation

Comment: Is it possible you could amend your example so that the column B entries are _not_ strictly increasing, then? Otherwise the impression is a little misleading. Also, could you answer my other question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh well. I'll go ahead and presume that you have Excel 2010 or later.

With e.g. "John" in D1, enter this formula in E1:

=SUMIFS($B$1:$B$10,$A$1:$A$10,D1,$B$1:$B$10,"<="&AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$1:$B$10/($A$1:$A$10=D1),5))

Copy down to give similar results for names in D2, D3, etc.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

## Formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)<=5,SUMIF($A$1:A1,A1,$B$1:B1),"")
```

The last value shown for each person will be the sum of the first (up to)5 values for that person.  Just copy and paste values then sort.

Comment: Thanks.  Very close.  But same comment as below.  Unfortunately there are 20 unique items in Column A all of which require the same summation. I believe I would need to do this 20 times in columns D-W, once for each unique item in A?

Comment: No you would not.  It gives you the sum for each name.

Answer (score 2):

Your sample data would show the same result for either the first 5 or lowest 5 as John's numbers are in ascending order. If that is not always the case or if you need to provide compatibility to versions of Excel earlier than 2010 I would offer the following. Note that in my sample image, I've resorted the numerical values in descending order to illustrate the difference.

For John's *first 5* values (E2 in the sample image):

```
=SUM(INDEX(($B$2:$B$11)*($A$2:$A$11=D2)*(ROW($1:$10)<=SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$10)+($A$2:$A$11<>D2)*1E+99,,), 5)),,))
```

For John's *lowest 5* values (F2 in the sample image):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(INDEX(($B$2:$B$11)+($A$2:$A$11<>D2)*1E+99,,),ROW($1:$5)))
```

These are standard formulas. Any array processing is supplied by `INDEX` and/or `SUMPRODUCT`. Ctrl+Shift+Enter is *not* required. Some form of error control may be necessary when there are less than 5 matching values; a simple `IF(COUNTIF(), <formula>)` would suffice. When transcribing these type of formulas it is important to note that ROW(1:10) is the *position within* B2:B11 or A2:A11, not the actual row on the worksheet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(A1="John",1,0)
```

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="John",1+MAX($C$1:C1),0)
```

and copy down.  Then use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A="John")*(B:B)*(C:C<6))
```

.
[image: pic]

Comment: Unfortunately there are 20 unique items in Column A all of which require the same summation.  I believe I would need to do this 20 times in columns D-W, once for each unique item in A?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming John in D1 you can get the sum of the 5 smallest values for John with this array formula

`=SUM(SMALL(IF(A$1:A$100=D1,B$1:B$100),{1,2,3,4,5}))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy down for to work for all names in the list