# SUMIF for first 5 cells meeting criteria, with moving window

Tags: arrays, excel, sum

I am looking to find a formula that calculates the cumulative points a team has for its last 5 games (so the first 5 games would have no values) in the last column. So it should return a number between 0 and 15. In the image below you can see an extract of the dataset. The range can also not continue to move down because then for the last 4 games, only the last 4, 3, 2, 1 game points would be added (hope I did not confuse you more).

I have tried to use SUMIF, SUMIFS with relative row numbers in the cell address within a function but sadly, that did not help. I also looked at [SUMIF for first 5 cells meeting criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218914/sumif-for-first-5-cells-meeting-criteria) but that did not make me any wiser.

Link to the full dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/thu7f8ajsz9g8wtfo9q2w/Data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=aq8d7xi4zyg7hvkophsrhswpi

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
FTHG = Full-Time Home Goals
FTAG = Full-Time Away Goals
FTR = Full-Time Result
PH = Points Home
PA = Points Away
```

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Version 16.47.1

Comment: Which team's points (home or away) do you want in the fifth column?  Do you have Power Query in your Excel version?

Comment: In the fifth column, I need the home team cumulative points of the last five games (afterwards I had a second column for the away team). And I think I have Power Query (but I'm not 100% sure because I am working on a Mac).

Comment: Are new games inserted at the top or the bottom of the table?  And do you want last 5 relative to the entire data set?  Or relative to the current game?

Comment: I want them to be relative to the current game. So, for Home Team Game X, Sum Points Game X-1, X-2, X-3, X-4 and X-5. Here is a link to the full dataset for one season: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/thu7f8ajsz9g8wtfo9q2w/Data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=aq8d7xi4zyg7hvkophsrhswpi

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really get what you want, but I have used two vlookup's to collect PH and PA and add them using a list of unique names from column A.

[image]

Here is the formula as text:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J4,$A$4:$H$20,6,0),0)+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J4,$B$4:$H$20,6,0),0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. However, for the sample data I gave you the result would be 0 for all the cells because no team has played 5 games yet. I will upload a full season's worth of data for you to try it out. I hope you understand more what I am trying to attempt here.

Comment: @SebHuy so are you saying intermediate results should not be counted until a particular team has actually completed 5 games? That is difficult, read impossible, to divine from your question. I will leave you to consider how to expand this as you need it. I think I have an answer to another question which uses aggregate() and that combined would likely work.

Comment: Thanks for your help already! So what I am trying to do is to add up all the points a team has for the past 5 games they played. For example: For game 6 of Bayern Munchen I want to have the sum of the points from the first 5 games. For game 15, for example, I would need the sum of the points from game 10-14. Here is a link to the full dataset of one season: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/thu7f8ajsz9g8wtfo9q2w/Data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=aq8d7xi4zyg7hvkophsrhswpi

Answer (score 0):

Given your original table and assuming that for any particular row, you are interested in the five games above that row (played by the same home team), you can use:

```
=LET(x,FILTER(G2:$G$2, B2:$B$2=B2),IF(COUNT(x)>=5,SUM(INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(5))),0))
```

You can see the first NON-ZERO result is in Row 65

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your attempt at solving my problem. I'm not sure the solution you gave solves my problem entirely. The last 5 changes as soon as a team has played a new game. There are 34 games in this competition, so because I want the last 5 games, the last 5 will change 29 times (I hope what I mean is clear). For example: For game 6 of Bayern Munchen I want to have the sum of the points from the first 5 games. For game 15, for example, I would need the sum of the points from game 10-14.

Comment: @SebHuy Since the games in your sample data set are not numbered, my skills are unable to determine which is the first game and which is the last.  But it's probably just a matter of changing the selected range to process.

Comment: I will try using that and will give you an update! Thanks!

Comment: I added some extra columns (Cumulative points Home/Away for the entire season, number of games played). So the column MH tells you this is the Xth game of the home team. Hop that gives you what you need to help me figure this out :-) https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/thu7f8ajsz9g8wtfo9q2w/Data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=aq8d7xi4zyg7hvkophsrhswpi

Comment: @SebHuy See my last edit for a formula that doesn't require adding columns.  It uses functions that are said to be present in Excel Office 365 for Mac

Comment: We are getting there! The only problem is that this will only make the sum of the last 5 home games, while I am looking to the last 5 games (so 3 home/2 away or the other way around). I guess that that only requires a small tweak to the formula, but I am not entirely sure. Thanks for you solution already! Already a big step in the right direction!

Comment: @SebHuy Have you figured something out? I gave up on a formula approach and developed a Power Query approach.  My understanding is that, although you can use Power Query in O365 Excel Mac, you cannot author it, so I don't know how useful the code will be. I suppose VBA would be an option also, but if I were doing it in Windows, I would use the Dictionary object (also missing on the Mac; but there is an add-in that provides that functionality).

Comment: @Rin Rosenfeld, I was able to solve it by adding two collumns for the number of matches played and then I was able to do it using only SUMIFS. Link: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/yuo25iiel2iagg9pxw8ia/Data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=5fk9cd2jy0padzrh7xxzxscjm Let me know if you have any questions!